# How should I define the module to add controllers to it?

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-controller, controllers

I've got my angular app setup something like this:

```
<div class="main" ng-app="myApp">
    <div class="sub" ng-controller="sub1">
        ...
    </div>
    <div class="sub" ng-controller="sub2">
        ...
    </div>
    <div class="sub" ng-controller="sub3">
        ...
    </div>
</div>
```

And the controllers each on different js file so the file structure is like:

```
Templates
-> home.html
Controllers
-> sub1Controller
-> sub2Controller
-> sub3Controller
```

In each controller file, I add the controller to the app by doing

```
ngApp.controller("sub1", function($scope){ ... });
```

And in the html file I linked the scripts.
After a few takes on getting the got undefined error, I found out that I am creating a new app on every directive, because to get the `ngApp` I used `angular.module("myApp", [])`, unlike `angular.module("myApp")` that would retrieve the module. So basically my question is, where should I define the module? Since doing `angular.module("myApp")` won't work before `angular.module("myApp", [])` is invoked I can't use the one without the brackets always. Is defining the module on the containing page a bad practice? Is separating the controllers to different files instead of all in the same one a bad practice?

Comment: Define the module in some "app.js" file, and make sure it comes before the controller scripts in the HTML page.

Comment: @JBNizet So basically adding a script tag before the controllers that has angular.module("myApp", []) in it is the best practice there is?

Comment: Yes. With a clever build procedure, injecting the scripts into the HTML can be done automatically.

Comment: having this separate file becomes especially nice when things start to get more complex, for example
`var myApp = angular.module('myApp', [
  'textAngular',
  'flow',
  'ngLodash'
]);

myApp.config(['$httpProvider', function AppConfig($httpProvider) {
  $httpProvider.defaults.withCredentials = true;
}]);`

Answer (score 0):

Separating controllers out into separate files is definitely a good idea, and I commend you for doing so. I'd recommend adding additional file above the controllers directory to define the angular module.

```
templates
-> home.html
js
->
  angular_config.js
  controllers
    -> sub1Controller
    -> sub2Controller
    -> sub3Controller
```

Answer (score 0):

There is nothing wrong with having all your controllers in the same file but for simplicity and future complexity reasons it is better to store each controller in a separate file.

A good solution may be to put all your controllers in controller folder(what you are currently doing ) 
the second thing is load another file that you can call app.js which will link all the controllers and other stuff together for example

in your  **app.js**  in the the js folder you can write :

```
window.onload = function(){

   var app = angular.module('mymodal',[]);

   app.controller('sub1Controller',function(){});
   app.controller('sub2Controller',function(){});
   app.controller('sub2Controller',function(){});

};
```

and then in your **index.*** file load js files in the following order

```
<script src="js/controllers/sub1Controller.js"></script>
<script src="js/controllers/sub2Controller.js"></script>
<script src="js/controllers/sub3Controller.js"></script>
<script src="js/app.js"></script>
```

By the way you can concatenate all your controllers files in one single file using task runner tools like grunt or gulp.